# Sending e-mail in C#, Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed

Tags: c#, smtp

I am trying to sent an e-mail with my C# application.
For some reason I get the following error: "Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed"

I have already tried to set the port to 25, 465 and 587.
I have also tried changing the settings to GMAIL Server and that is working fine.
These are the settings given by the hosting company I'm using.
https://www.versio.nl/assets/faq/Schermafbeelding%202012-10-17%20om%2017.25.10.png

This is my code I am using to sent the e-mail:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("mail.SMTPSERVEUR.Foo");

mail.From = new MailAddress("info@SiteWeb.Foo");
mail.To.Add("SenderAddress@hotmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail";

SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@SiteWeb.Foo", "************");
 SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: where is mail.axc.nl why does it talk of gmail when thats not a gmail server, and you should remove your password and are you sure there are no firewalls

Comment: Remove password! And use smtp.gmail.com with port 587 and account data from gmail login if you want to send using gmail

Comment: I need it to sent e-mail from the SMTP server of Versio. I don't want it to send e-mail from the SMTP server of GMAIL.

Comment: Maybe it's the mailserver that isn't working?

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Comment: Yes, I know. Not very smart of me. But I changed my password as soon as I noticed I posted a password.